# How does joblib.Parallel deal with global variables?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, joblib

My code looks something like this:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

# prediction model - 10s of megabytes on disk
LARGE_MODEL = load_model('path/to/model')

file_paths = glob('path/to/files/*')

def do_thing(file_path):
  pred = LARGE_MODEL.predict(load_image(file_path))
  return pred

Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(do_thing)(fp) for fp in file_paths)
```

My question is whether `LARGE_MODEL` will be pickled/unpickled with each iteration of the loop. And if so, how can I make sure each worker caches it instead (if that's possible)?

Comment: Are we talking Windows or *NIX here? I believe that in terms of *NIX and fork() `LARGE_MODEL` will be copied. And pickling applies only to `file_path`, as mentioned in the manual of joblib.Parallel

Comment: Not sure what *NIX is. I'm on Ubuntu. I'm starting to get the feeling that my question is nonsensical seeing as I'm getting no answers. Maybe I'll read the manual

Comment: Well, it's not nonsensical at all, it's just.... really specific about implementation of the library which is not the most popular :}

Comment: Ah it's not popular? What is then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TLDR**

> The parent process pickles large model once. That can be made more performant by ensuring large model is a numpy array backed to a memfile. Workers can [`load_temporary_memmap`](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/blob/0.17.0/joblib/numpy_pickle.py#L522) much faster than from disk.

Your job is parallelized and likely to be using `joblibs._parallel_backends.LokyBackend`.

In [`joblib.parallel.Parallel.__call__`](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/blob/0.17.0/joblib/parallel.py#L965), joblib tries to initialize the backend to use `LokyBackend` when `n_jobs` is set to a [count greater than 1](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/blob/0.17.0/joblib/_parallel_backends.py#L490).

`LokyBackend` uses a shared temporary folder for the same `Parallel` object. This is relevant for reducers that modify the default pickling behavior.

Now, `LokyBackend` configures a `MemmappingExecutor` that [shares this folder](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/blob/0.17.0/joblib/executor.py#L48) to the `reducers`.

If you have [numpy installed](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/blob/0.17.0/joblib/_memmapping_reducer.py#L488) and your model is a clean [numpy array](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/blob/0.17.0/joblib/_memmapping_reducer.py#L383), you are guaranteed to have it **pickled once** as a memmapped file using the [ArrayMemmapForwardReducer](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/blob/0.17.0/joblib/_memmapping_reducer.py#L313) and passed from parent to child processes.

Otherwise it is pickled [using the default pickling](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/blob/0.17.0/joblib/_memmapping_reducer.py#L470) as a `bytes` object.

You can know how your model is pickled in the parent process reading the debug logs from joblib.

Each worker 'unpickles' large model so there is really no point in caching the large model there.

You can only improve the source from where the pickled large model is loaded from in the workers by backing your models as a [memory mapped file](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html).